# Costumize style of the selected (current) FlyoutItem

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I've noticed that when I customize flyout item appearance like it says here [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout#define-flyoutitem-appearance), the current FlyoutItem is not marked anymore.

Snip of the code from docs to change the item appearance:

```xml
<Shell ...>
    ...
    <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                       Margin="5"
                       HeightRequest="45" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Title}"
                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>
</Shell>
```

[Screenshot before Shell.ItemTemplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89cXB.png)
[Screenshot after Shell.ItemTemplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV3DE.png)

One would assume there must also be some kind of Shell.**Current/Active/Selected**ItemTemplate customization, but I can not find it.

Any ideas how I can customize current shell item appearance, or at least make the default item marking work with Shell.ItemTemplate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Unfortunately**.From [Xamarin.Forms - Xaminals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/) sample , also occurs this phenomenon. **This should be a limit of Shell FlyoutItem in Current version of XF**.

```
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                Margin="5"
                HeightRequest="45" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
                Text="{Binding Title}"
                FontAttributes="Italic"
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

If not using `Shell.ItemTemplate` , selectitem is marked:

[image]

Else selectitem is not marked :

[image]

===================================**UPDATE**================================

**Solution**:

If adding style to the template , can hold the selected state after selecting.

**Shell.Resources**: adding a *FloutItemStyle*.

```
<Style x:Key="FloutItemStyle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Accent"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Using in **Shell.ItemTemplate** as follow:

```
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource FloutItemStyle}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
        Margin="5"
        HeightRequest="45" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
        Text="{Binding Title}"
        FontAttributes="Italic"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

Finally showing the effect:

[image]

Comment: My question was not about how to mark a current item. It was why current item does not get marked automatically anymore if i change item appearance, and how to fix it.

Comment: I have tested your answer just in case and it turns out that CurrentItem is not used to control what item in the flyout appears as current. Setting the CurrentItem actually navigates to that item (the item is still not marked in the flyout). So I'm afraid your answer has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: @Dudu Sorry for mistaking your question . You can have a try with this sample (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/). When selecting one item, after backing it also be marked.

Comment: @Jiang I've checked there before, but Xaminals doesnt seem to be using <Shell.ItemTemplate> but rather <Shell.Resources> and styles, and I cant seem to find much about that in the documentation, certainly not under modifying flyout item appearance... do you know where I could find more information?

Comment: @Dudu Yeah , you are right. If using `Shell.ItemTemplate` , the selection status will disappear .This is the limit of Shell `FlyoutItem`.Hoping this will be improved later.

Comment: @Dudu Hi, I found a solution to hold the selected state. I wll updated in answer .

Comment: @Jiang Wow that actually works, thank you very much! Do you maybe know how I could also change some other elements, like the text color of the current element? I have tried making another style with TargetType="Label" for the text, where I set the textColor, but it does not work. My best guess is that the label of current item does not have its visual state set as "Selected", like the grid does. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Dudu Because bellow `Selected` state, there is no `TextColor` property to set. If want to add Text Style , there is no selected or unselected state , just all the way changed color. About `Style` using , here is a document to be referred.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/explicit

Comment: Are you sure that with this way you are only modifying the background property without affecting anything else from the default style ? I tried to apply it and it seems other thing have been changed along with the background color

Comment: @Cfun Hi, what do you mean that other thing have been changed along with the background color. You could create a new question, and share with a screenshot and code to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binding property. Create a custom grid

```
public class ShellItemGrid : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedColorProperty =       BindableProperty.Create("SelectedColor", typeof(Color), typeof(ShellItemGrid),Color.Transparent);

    public Color SelectedColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Define the style for the grid

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FlyoutItemStyle" TargetType="controls:ShellItemGrid">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">                      
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="SelectedColor" Value="Red"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="SelectedColor" Value="White"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Define the item template and bind the TextColor of the Label to the SelectedColor of the grid

```
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <controls:ShellItemGrid x:Name="mGrid" Style="{StaticResource FlyoutItemStyle}" >
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" 
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="20,10,0,10"
                   Text="{Binding Title}"                        
                   TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference mGrid},Path=SelectedColor}"
                   FontSize="18" />
            </controls:ShellItemGrid >
    </DataTemplate>

</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```