# How to change selected Flyoutitem background color

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I change color of a selected FlyOutItem ? Let's say I want it to be blue instead of gray in the screenshot below.

I downloaded a few sample projects like Gastropods and went through all FlyOutItem styling properties ( it seems ) but can't figure it out.[image]

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Costumize style of the selected (current) FlyoutItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57421964/costumize-style-of-the-selected-current-flyoutitem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution :**

You can add a style of Item .

In **Shell.Resource**

```
<Style x:Key="FloutItemStyle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And use it in **Shell.ItemTemplate**

```
<Shell.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource FloutItemStyle}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
        Margin="5"
        HeightRequest="45" />
            <Label Grid.Column="1"
        Text="{Binding Title}"
        FontAttributes="Italic"
        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Setting style on the grid as you showed worked! Thank you very much!